# Фон из гардиента

Tags: css

Как сделать фон из гардиента? Я сделал в css генераторе вот такой фон и получился вот такой код:

```
background: #2821ff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2821ff 0%, #00a2ff 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2821ff), color-stop(100%,#00a2ff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2821ff 0%,#00a2ff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #2821ff 0%,#00a2ff 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #2821ff 0%,#00a2ff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2821ff 0%,#00a2ff 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2821ff', endColorstr='#00a2ff',GradientType=0 );
```

А вот  как выглядит он на сайте: http://prntscr.com/1oo0wf
Смысл в том, что мне надо гардиент сделать так чтоб он не замостеным, т.е. одна и та же картинка много раз.

Comment: Добавьте в css:

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

Comment: Извините, вопрос не в тему: что такое "замостеным"?

Comment: Как же я сразу недодумался, это легко))

Comment: @zhenyab, другими словами - повторить бэкграунд. И да, наверно, правильней "**замощенным**"

Comment: У меня появилась ещё кое какая проблема. 
http://prntscr.com/1yh840 - гардиент начал заново делаться, как сделать, чтоб он растягивался, а не просто набрал определенную высоту и начал заново выростать

Comment: Задайте в 100% не height, а min-height

Comment: **градиент**